# How to find associated records from 2 many to many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following models

```
Business has many Categories through Categorizations
Category has many Businesses through Categorizations

Business has many Estates through Localizations
Estate has many Businesses through Localizations
```

How would I find all the categories of the businesses for a certain estate?

@categories = Find all Categories from a certain estate's businesses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be an easier way, but you can always try this:

```
@estate = Estate.find(1)

@estate.businesses.map {|business| business.categories}.flatten
```

or

```
@estate = Estate.find(1)

@categories = Categories.where(id: @estate.businesses.pluck(:id))
```

Comment: Thanks. The first one works but gives duplicates. How can I get unique values. The second one gives the following error: SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: id: SELECT id FROM "businesses" INNER JOIN "localizations" ON "businesses"."id" = "localizations"."business_id" WHERE "localizations"."estate_id" = 1

Comment: hey, the second one works for me, i'm using MYSQL, i guess that is the difference. if the first one is working but gives duplicates just add the `'.uniq'` method at the end.